# Cumsum starting value not 0 in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.x

I have the following dataframe `df` of athletes (indexed by `Athlete_ID`) and their Rank (indexed by `Rank`), here is a slide of the dataframe with a particular athlete:

```
Rank    Athlete_ID  Date
13      143         25/4/2021
1       143         5/4/2021
6       143         24/2/2021
11      143         24/1/2021
4       143         1/1/2021
9       143         13/12/2020
8       143         22/11/2020
1       143         23/9/2020
9       143         6/9/2020
10      143         20/5/2020
1       143         18/3/2020
7       143         26/2/2020
1       143         29/1/2020
1       143         18/12/2019
1       143         20/11/2019
7       143         2/3/2019
4       143         10/2/2019
7       143         27/6/2018
9       143         6/5/2018
2       143         7/1/2018
2       143         17/12/2017
1       143         5/11/2017
3       143         8/10/2017
```

I want to count the total number of wins (rank number 1) and recent number of wins (number of wins in this year), here is my code:

```
df['Athle_total_wins']=df.sort_values(['Athlete_ID','Date'],ascending=[True,True])['Rank'].shift(1).eq(1).groupby(df['Athlete_ID']).cumsum()
 
df['Athle_recent_wins']=df.sort_values(['Athlete_ID','Date'],ascending=[True,True])['Rank'].shift(1).eq(1).groupby([df['Athlete_ID'],df['Date'].dt.year]).cumsum()
```

and the output is

```
Rank    Athlete_ID  Date        Athle_total_wins    Athle_recent_wins
13      143         25/4/2021   8                   1
1       143         5/4/2021    7                   0
6       143         24/2/2021   7                   0
11      143         24/1/2021   7                   0
4       143         1/1/2021    7                   0
9       143         13/12/2020  7                   4
8       143         22/11/2020  7                   4
1       143         23/9/2020   6                   3
9       143         6/9/2020    6                   3
10      143         20/5/2020   6                   3
1       143         18/3/2020   5                   2
7       143         26/2/2020   5                   2
1       143         29/1/2020   4                   1
1       143         18/12/2019  3                   1
1       143         20/11/2019  2                   0
7       143         2/3/2019    2                   0
4       143         10/2/2019   2                   0
7       143         27/6/2018   2                   0
9       143         6/5/2018    2                   0
2       143         7/1/2018    2                   0
2       143         17/12/2017  2                   2
1       143         5/11/2017   1                   1
3       143         8/10/2017   1                   1
```

which is almost what I want but not exactly because the last row doesn't start at 0 (i.e. something is wrong for the last year in 2017, or the last few rows). The desired output should be

```
Rank    Athlete_ID  Date        Athle_total_wins    Athle_recent_wins
13      143         25/4/2021   7                   1
1       143         5/4/2021    6                   0
6       143         24/2/2021   6                   0
11      143         24/1/2021   6                   0
4       143         1/1/2021    6                   0
9       143         13/12/2020  6                   4
8       143         22/11/2020  6                   4
1       143         23/9/2020   5                   3
9       143         6/9/2020    5                   3
10      143         20/5/2020   5                   3
1       143         18/3/2020   4                   2
7       143         26/2/2020   4                   2
1       143         29/1/2020   3                   1
1       143         18/12/2019  2                   1
1       143         20/11/2019  1                   0
7       143         2/3/2019    1                   0
4       143         10/2/2019   1                   0
7       143         27/6/2018   1                   0
9       143         6/5/2018    1                   0
2       143         7/1/2018    1                   0
2       143         17/12/2017  1                   1
1       143         5/11/2017   0                   1
3       143         8/10/2017   0                   0
```

Comment: When I ran your code on your provided data I got your desired output. Is there something in the data that you haven't provided that could be affecting your results?

Answer (score 0):

Get the total number of wins per `Athlete_ID`:

```
print( df.where(df.Rank == 1).groupby([df.Athlete_ID]).agg({'Rank': 'count'}) )
#            Rank
#Athlete_ID
#143            7
```

Get the number of wins per `Athlete_ID` and `Date.year`:

```
print( df.where(df.Rank == 1).groupby([df.Athlete_ID, df.Date.dt.year]).agg({'Rank': 'count'}) )
#                 Rank
#Athlete_ID Date
#143        2017     1
#           2018     0
#           2019     2
#           2020     3
#           2021     1
```